# Wrong result if fetching table data after update

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I try to update a row in a table and when I retrieve the row's values I find the string "images".

I have a function to add all id of articles which should be displayed in the main page.

My code is:

```
function add_article($id) {    
   if($id != '') {
       //get value from table {ex: $articles->to_main_page = '1 | 6'}
       $articles = $this->settings_model->getBy('to_main_page');

       //convert $id to string $id = 5
       $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
       //$id = strval($id);

       $val = $articles->valuesetting . ' | ' . $id; //it has to be $val = '1 | 6 | 5'

       //update table
       $this->settings_model->update('to_main_page', $val);
    }
   redirect('settings');
}
```

before I update I check variable with `var_dump($val)` and it's ok `$val = '1 | 6 | 5'`

But when I fetch this row after update I find ('1 | 6 | 5 **| images**'). "*images*" should not be there.

My table structure is

```
settings
( idsettings        varchar(50), 
  valuesettings     varchar(100)
)
```

Comment: what's the structure of the table?

Comment: Looks like $id == 'images' before it hits the if statement. What did you expect it to be? How should it not be empty before going into the if statement? Explain your logic.

Comment: in this row(settings(varchar)) I add all id of articles ho should to be displayed to main page.
I check if id is empty then do nothing. I get this id from url ..../settings/add_article/6

Comment: var_dump($id); If its returns "images", Check your pathing and routing to make sure they're correct.